# How can I use GDI+ in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, gdi+

I have problems when using GDI+ in WPF. It's was okay in WindowsForm. But in WPF I can't create a graphic object follow [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983623(v=vs.71).aspx), there is no a Graphics class. The controls in WPF also don't have CreateGraphics method. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you think it's even possible? You are right in that there is no `Graphics` class in WPF. The graphics engine in WPF work completely different than Windows Forms.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is my mini project at school and my teacher said that we had to use GDI+ to make a simple paint program - a WPF application. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF is not based on GDI+, and doesn't use the Graphics class and similar at all.  In general, if you're doing drawing in WPF, you'd use completely different techniques.

That being said, WPF can interop with other desktop technologies, like GDI+, though it's typically less ideal to go this route.

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`WindowsFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx) to host Windows Forms content, including the GDI+ information, into your WPF application.  You could then use standard Windows Forms controls, which will provide the graphics API you're expecting, and just embed it into a WPF container.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. :) I just have a stupid question.